# ReferenceError: HighCharts is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'm rendering a chart using highstocks on my rails application on a index.html.erb file, however when I try to load the chart, I get the following error on the firebug console,

```
ReferenceError: HighCharts is not defined
new HighCharts.Chart({
```

My index.html.erb file is as follows

```
<div id="quotes_chart", style="width=560px; height:300px;">
<script>
 $(function(){   
 new HighCharts.Chart({
  chart : {
   renderTo: "quotes_chart"
  },
  title : {
   text: "Daily trades" 
  },
  xAxis : {
    type: "datetime"
  },
  yAxis : {
    title: {
     text: "Shillings"
   }
  },
  tooltip : {
    formatter: function(){
      return HighCharts.dateFormat("%B %e, %Y", this.x) + ': ' + "Kshs" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
    }
  },
  series: [
    <% { "Telecommunication" => StockQuote.telecomm, "Agriculture" => StockQuote.agric }.each do |name, prices|
%>
{
  name: <%= name %>,
  pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
  pointStart: <%= 2.weeks.ago.to_i * 1000 %>,
  data: <%= (2.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.today).map { |date| StockQuote.price_on(date).to_f}.inspect%>
},
<% end %>
]
});
});
</script>
</div>
```

In my application.html.erb is as follows:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="components/highstock/highstock.js"></script>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.11.0.min", "highcharts" %>
```

In my app assests/javascripts folder I have both the jquery-1.11.0.min.js and highcharts.js files as downloaded from highcharts.com

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load Highcharts only once, not twice as you have. So, I recommend to use only:

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="components/highstock/highstock.js"></script>
```

Because Highstock includes all Highcharts options. Morever please take care about correct paths to your files, because it looks like a problem only with it.

Answer (score 5):

```
var chart=null;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'bar'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: '${model.title}'
                    }
...
```

Set the chart to null because this error can occur due to multiple declaration that you may not be  aware of. Assumption is all imports are correct